# How to revert back from Marshmallow 6 to Lollipop 5 in Samsung Note 4?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

My Samsung Note 4 is updated to 6, but I don't like it and I want to go back to Lollipop. Is it possible to do it easily?

I heard that there are many problems with 6.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly the downgrade isn't so easy at all.

You have to download a proper official Samsung Galaxy Note 4 Lollipop system image from [SamFirmware](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/) and install it from Odin (or Heimdall on OS X). You have to read about this process before you do anything (eg.: enable developer options, USB debugging, etc)

It will be a clean install so if you have any important app or app-data you should backup all of them (I prefer [TitaniumBackup Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup), but you have to be rooted.) with Kies (if you aren't rooted).

If you stuck there is a [guide](http://justforprogrammers.blogspot.hu/2015/12/downgrade-from-marshmallow-to-lollipop.html) for a Samsung Galaxy S6.

Comment: It is generally better to include the full explanation of the procedure in an answer, rather than just links. Those may get outdated and thus become dead-ends, so it's advised to use them only as references.

Comment: One more thing - Samsung's bootloaders typically disallow downgrading, though I don't know if that the case with Marshmallow -> Lollipop. Care to back up with successful examples? OP will have more incentive to take the risk if you do.